# Expand data.frame into distinct rows

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to figure out how I can expand a data.frame in R into distinct rows. By this, I mean using startyear and toyear variables to create an annual data.frame where id is replicated for each distinct year in the sequence from=startyear to=endyear.

I have an example data.frame:

```
testdat <- data.frame(id=seq(1,10),
           startyear=c(1946,1960,1965,1976,1955,1999,2013,1981,1983,1995)
           )

testdat$endyear <- testdat$startyear+sample(1:10,10,replace=TRUE)
```

This creates:

```
  id startyear endyear
1  1      1946    1951
2  2      1960    1966
3  3      1965    1969
.  .      ....    ....
```

What my desired result would look like is this:

```
id year
1  1946
1  1947
1  1948
1  1949
1  1950
1  1951
2  1960
.  ....
```

Any advice on how to do this would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Similar.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30602821/r-creating-a-sequence-table-from-two-columns. So for ex, Akruns answer. `library(data.table) ; setDT(testdat)[, list(year=startyear:endyear), by = id]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the "Hadley'verse", namely `dplyr` and `tidyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
testdat %>% 
  group_by(id) %>%
  expand(year=full_seq(c(startyear, endyear), 1))
# Source: local data frame [64 x 2]
# Groups: id [10]
# 
#       id  year
#    (int) (dbl)
# 1      1  1946
# 2      1  1947
# 3      1  1948
# 4      1  1949
# 5      1  1950
# 6      1  1951
# 7      1  1952
# 8      2  1960
# 9      2  1961
# 10     3  1965
# ..   ...   ...
```

Comment: Thanks for providing a working code in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`melt`from the package `reshape`can handle this:

```
library(reshape)
melt(testdat, id.vars  = c("id"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking to convert from wide format to long format.

The `gather` function from the [tidyr](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/index.html) package can do this.

There's an comprehensive example in the [Cookbook for R](http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Converting_data_between_wide_and_long_format/).